# Amazon MWS Product API How to retrieve Sales Rank and Merchant Name

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I've been experimenting heavily with the different MWS API's. I'm trying to retrieve the following info about my items:

1 - Number of offers - Available via GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU

2 - Number of FBA offers - Available via GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU

3 - Sales Rank of product - ?

4 - Competitive Price (buy box) - Available via GetCompetitivePricingForSKU

5 - Names of other merchants offering product - ?

6 - Price of offers - Available via GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU

The two elements I cannot find are Sales rank and names of other merchants

These both seem to be available via the Product Advertising API but not the MWS Product API as per [this example here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_OfferFull.html).

It was my (perhaps incorrect) understanding that the Product MWS API was mostly the same thing as the Product Advertising API except that the former is designed for sellers and the latter for others to sell on their own sites.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. The MWS API lets you work with *your own* data - it basically is an alternative to Seller Central. The Product Advertising API lets you access public data - it is an alternative to browsing the www.amazon.com website. To get sales rank information and a list of offers from different merchants, check the various `ResponseGroup`s for the [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) call.

Comment: Thank you. There is much info on-line from 2012 on how Amazon was not allowing sellers to use the PA API. There is also talk on how one cannot see the merchant name anymore. I'm assuming this is old info and it can be done?

Comment: I've been fooling around with the PA API and it seems far more robust and advanced than the MWS API. However it appears to be strictly geared towards Amazon Associates. I do not operate as an associate but I do want access to this data to gain insight into products I'm already selling Is this what others use for this? Or is there some way to do it within MWS? Thanks!

Comment: @user2029890 I haven't done much with the Product Advertising API, but quite a bit with MWS. It is my understanding that PA API is geared towards associates but can be used to get information about your own products. Even with the latest enhancements, some of that information is not currently available through MWS. If you're worried that such usage is against Amazon usage agreements, you should ask them directly (and preferrably post their answer here)

Answer (score 2):

The MWS Product API, specifically `getMatchingProductForId`, will give you sales rank, on some skus that are children of parents, you have to `getMatchingProductForId` on the parent in order to get the sales rank of the parent as the child might not have it.  additionally, it gives it to you on a per-category basis.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html).  If you subscribe to those push notifications (it uses Amazon SQS), you'll get price change notifications on any product you sell if any of the top 20 change in price.  The data you are returned will show you the other merchant id's as well as their rank and loads of other information like buy box owner, landed price, shipping price, feedback rating and count.. etc. etc.

We use these notifications to re-price our products in near real time based on how the competition moves.

Comment: Thanks (slow response I know). I tried this. The problem with this is it only shows items that have a price change. I want to see all my items whether or not there is a price change.  Also, my items are all variations and SalesRank is not returned at all. I'm guessing because individual variations do not have rank. Only the parent ASIN.