# How to retrieve current sale price and dates via MWS / Amazon Reports

Tags: amazon-mws

I've looked through all the report documentation I can find and the various MWS operations, but I cannot for the life of me find any way to retrieve the currently set sale price, sale start date and sale end date for the SKUs we are currently selling.

For clarification: I am trying to retrieve the SALE price, not the standard 'listing price'. When editing an item directly via Seller Central these fields are labelled `Sale Price`, `Sale From Date` and `Sale End Date`. Which are separate to the main price, which is labelled `Your price`.

Is my search-fu lacking or is this information not retrievable via MWS (either directly or via some report or another)?

Many thanks!

C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call GetMyPriceForSKU and supply your SKU you will get back results that will include the following:

```
<Offers>
  <Offer>
    <BuyingPrice>
      <LandedPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>217.76</Amount>
      </LandedPrice>
      <ListingPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>189.00</Amount>
      </ListingPrice>
      <Shipping>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>28.76</Amount>
      </Shipping>
    </BuyingPrice>
    <RegularPrice>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>199.00</Amount>
    </RegularPrice>
    <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
    <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
    <SellerId>YOURSELLERID</SellerId>
    <SellerSKU>YOUR_SKU</SellerSKU>
  </Offer>
</Offers>
```

This example is a Product that has a Sale Price set in Seller Central.

You will see that the ListingPrice is 189.00. This is the Sale Price.

```
      <ListingPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>189.00</Amount>
      </ListingPrice>
```

Below you will see RegularPrice is 199.00. This is the normal Price.

```
    <RegularPrice>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>199.00</Amount>
    </RegularPrice>
```

The example below is from a Product that does not have a Sale Price set. Notice the ListingPrice and RegularPrice are the same.

```
  <Offer>
    <BuyingPrice>
      <LandedPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>33.60</Amount>
      </LandedPrice>
      <ListingPrice>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>24.45</Amount>
      </ListingPrice>
      <Shipping>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <Amount>9.15</Amount>
      </Shipping>
    </BuyingPrice>
    <RegularPrice>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>24.45</Amount>
    </RegularPrice>
    <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
    <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
    <SellerId>YOUR_SELLERID</SellerId>
    <SellerSKU>YOUR_SKU</SellerSKU>
  </Offer>
```

Unfortunately Amazon does not provide the Sale Begin and End dates through the feed. As of right now I dont know a way to retrieve those dates. If you wanted to find out all the Products on Sale you could simply compare ListingPrice and RegularPrice of each Product. When the Sale expires the ListingPrice will revert back to RegularPrice.

Comment: That's really helpful - thank you for pointing that out (I had missed it before), and it's a shame the sale dates are not available.

Answer (score 0):

_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_ in the Reports API will get you your listing price.  I usually determine the 'start' date by the first time I am able to pull inventory data, or product data.  I don't know that there are fields available for the start date.  As for the end date, I'm a bit confused on this because Amazon isn't an auction type system so to my knowledge, as long as you keep inventory levels positive, it should just stay listed? Anyone feel free to correct this..

Also, keep in mind.. I believe you can find the listing start date, but I have found that if you add your item to an existing listing, or if your listings get combined with other sellers pre-existing listings, that the 'start' of the listing is not synonymous with when you started selling the product.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear. I know how to get the current "listing price", but I'm trying to pull the "sale" price (i.e. temporary discounted price), along with the start and end dates of the sale period.

Comment: I'm seeing a few posts indicating that the Products API is where you need to look for sale pricing.  Amazon AWS has this in their product advertising api via Retrieve Pricing call.  A few posts indicate that in MWS, the Products API GetLowestPricedOffers call will get you what you need.  References:

Comment: [MWS Doc](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN.html)  //  [MWS Forum Post](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3517597) //   [Similar SO post.  See 'Price of Offers'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702502/amazon-mws-product-api-how-to-retrieve-sales-rank-and-merchant-name)  It appears that Amazon nomenclature between MWS and AWS is inconsistent.  You see Sale Price in AWS, but in MWS, it appears that this is referenced as an 'Offer' price.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. However, I'm not sure those links are helpful. I'm trying to retrieve (private) info about my own listings, to see which ones are currently "on sale" and the dates of the sale period. This is not exactly the same as "offer price", although offer price will tell me the current "buy price" for a given listing it does not tell me that it's a temporary (sale) price and does not tell me the (start or) end date of the sale. The Products API generally only shows "public" information, so I don't think that's the right way to go.

Comment: Another interesting note.. indicating that sale prices are indeed not available.  I know you can update the sale price  and times via the pricing Feed, but have been unable to find where to retrieve them.  Again, I think Offers may provide some information in relation to a sale price but it would be working around the system I suppose.  [Indicates Sales Price Not Available.](https://docs.wplab.com/article/91-import-sale-prices-from-amazon)